# No such slot MainWindow::showPreferencesWindow()

Tags: c++, qt

I will be glad if you could help me a little.
So as it is in topic I have error trying to do Q_OBJECT::connect.
So my code is:
preferences.h:

```
#include <QDialog>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QCoreApplication>
namespace Ui {
class Preferences;
}

class Preferences : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Preferences(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Preferences();


private:
    Ui::Preferences *ui;
};
```

preferences.cpp:

```
#include "preferences.h"
#include "ui_preferences.h"

Preferences::Preferences(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Preferences)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Preferences::~Preferences()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

mainwindow.h:

```
#include "preferences.h"
#include "addkierowca.h"


namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    Preferences *PreferencesWindow;
private:
/* some private methods */
void showPreferencesWindow();
```

And last but not least mainwindow.cpp:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->actionUstawiania, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(showPreferencesWindow()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::showPreferencesWindow()
{
    PreferencesWindow = new Preferences(this);
    PreferencesWindow->show();
    PreferencesWindow->exec();
}
```

I couldn't found anwser anywhere, and I know that there are almost same topics, but none of them helped me.
Thanks in advice.

Comment: Have you tried declaring the slot under `slots:`? Why do people still use the old connection syntax after 6 years of Qt 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using showPreferencesWindow as a slot in the connect so need to at it to a slot.

change to:

```
 private slots:
   void showPreferencesWindow();
```

At that point, moc (used by the makefile) will generate the correct code needed for connect to work correctly.

Comment: Thanks, that helped :)